# Magento URL rewrite after heavy traffic

Tags: magento-1.7, url

Whenever I have heavy traffic to certain page Magento adds "-1" to the URL and if the traffic maintains it adds "-1-1" and so so on. This makes it impossible to link back to my website.

Comment: Which "certain page"? And what do you mean by "Magento adds": is this how the link is built, or is this added via redirect? What happens when you try to visit this page directly and add -1 yourself?

Comment: The page that traffic directed to it. The link is not built with any -1, they don't get redirected they just get error 404

Answer (score 1):

The only time Magento will append `-1` to a URL is when you duplicate a product - it won't do it in any other circumstance.

Your issue will be caused by custom code.

Follow the debug guide to the letter, [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Comment: That exactly is mt point, they are not duplicates but it still adds the '-1'